# Is there any way to buy Adobe Illustrator instead of subscribing?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, licensing

Based on my other question [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/97720/what-software-do-you-recommend-for-creating-a-logo) I started googling the price of Adobe Illustrator and it looks like they only let you subscribe to a monthly payment. I couldn't find a direct way to buy AI and permanently own a license. Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: nope, unfortunately Adobe has moved to a subscription-only policy. Which sucks, I agree.

Comment: Does this mean like I do a monthly subscription, then if I finished whatever I wanted to finish using this software, I just don't subscribe anymore?

Comment: Also consider that the price of illustrator for buying was very high. You can rent it for about 40 months for the price.

Comment: If you don't want to pay anything, perhaps have a look a Inkscape(dot)org

Answer (score 9):

Until recently it was possible to buy the Adobe CS6 pack permanently as a one-time payment. But that is no longer an option and Adobe CC software is currently only available via subscriptions. Yeah, like going to the gym :)

- There is a free 7-day trial where you download, install and use the software for 7 days and then it becomes locked until a payment is made.
- There is an yearly plan where you pay 12 months in advance.
- There is also a monthly plan where you can use the software for 1, 2, 3, etc as many months as you need (until you cancel the plan or it expires). When your plan expires or it gets cancelled, the software remains installed, but you won't be able to use it until you renew your payment. You can go for the monthly plan, make 1 payment, then cancel the plan so it does not renew after 1 month (otherwise it will automatically renew).
- At any point in the future you can make another 1-month payment and reactivate the software for another 30 days.

Comment: Pretty sure they changed all the trials to 7 days now

Comment: You can still buy a perpetual license for CS6... **If** you can find it for sale somewhere. Adobe no longer sells it, but sometimes third party vendors will have old stock. Unfortunately, it's been years so I imagine most vendors have sold out of their stock. If they haven't sold out... prices have [SKYROCKETED](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B003B32AQK?psc=1).

Comment: @scott yeah with that kind of money you can buy a subscription for 7 years even more if you account for how much the moneys value changes.

Answer (score 2):

About 4 years ago Adobe closed the support for Creative Suite 2 including Illustrator CS2. That product was in wide use because it had and still has enough functionality for detailed professional graphic work. People couldn't run their CS2 because the software couldn't check from the activation server was it paid. Adobe published as a band-aid the last CS2 versions in their support&download pages modified to work without internet connection to the activation server. The working serial numbers were also available.

Obviously a massive downloading started and very soon Adobe moved all behind sign-in. That affects to me nothing because I am a paying customer. They ask nothing. But they know who I am because I can see my name in the upper corner of the browser.

Their webpage for the subject is:

https://helpx.adobe.com/creative-suite/kb/creative-suite-2-activation-end-life.html

You can check do they give anything to you. If they do, be sure that the software is unreliable in today's operating systems. I have seen that CS2 runs ok at least in Win7.

Comment: It also runs well in Mac OS.